# Converting a text file to GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson

I am using python, and I have a text file that contains the metadata of the area that I intend to use. Here is a sample:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "id": 10, "properties": { "circo_id": 220.0, "circo_na_1": "Jendouba" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 8.93042, 36.826946000000135 ], [ 8.930019, 36.820381 ], [ 8.929707, 36.813044000000104 ], [ 8.929579, 36.81000900000015 ], [ 8.925296, 36.800781 ], [ 8.925087, 36.798068 ], [ 8.92489, 36.795511000000147 ], [ 8.924849, 36.794975 ], [ 8.924617, 36.791961 ], [ 8.92791, 36.786500000000103 ], [ 8.94451, 36.784920000000113 ], [ 8.953495, 36.785014000000103 ], [ 8.963627, 36.785119 ], [ 8.978325, 36.783161 ], [ 8.995327000000145, 36.782618 ], [ 9.008783000000108, 36.778728000000115 ], [ 9.019933, 36.772889000000134 ], [ 9.02058, 36.772046 ], [ 9.022671, 36.76932 ], [ 9.02646, 36.76439 ], [ 9.031497, 36.754985 ], [ 9.033054000000106, 36.752078 ], [ 9.035473, 36.747559 ], [ 9.039081, 36.740821000000153 ], [ 9.039726, 36.739617 ], [ 9.04513500000013, 36.729512 ], [ 9.03746, 36.71935 ], [ 9.035804, 36.71577 ], [ 9.031620000000146, 36.70673 ], [ 9.02867, 36.70037 ], [ 9.024459, 36.687168 ], [ 9.02488, 36.682406 ], [ 9.025526, 36.675109 ], [ 9.026045, 36.673998 ], [ 9.027963, 36.669891000000121 ], [ 9.031041, 36.663299 ], [ 9.03759, 36.653061 ], [ 9.039488, 36.651221 ], [ 9.044067, 36.646782000000144 ], [ 9.047731, 36.643231000000128 ], [ 9.061971000000142, 36.629342 ], [ 9.073415, 36.61745900000011 ], [ 9.078124000000116, 36.609460000000126 ], [ 9.078296000000137, 36.609168000000125 ], [ 9.079749000000106, 36.606701000000101 ], [ 9.080025, 36.602885 ], [ 9.080585000000156, 36.59515 ], [ 9.07971700000013, 36.584081 ], [ 9.079463, 36.57542 ], [ 9.07932, 36.570438000000138 ], [ 9.078685, 36.567225 ], [ 9.07737, 36.560558000000128 ], [ 9.076425, 36.559185 ], [ 9.071587000000136, 36.55217 ], [ 9.063895, 36.543911000000151 ], [ 9.056668000000116, 36.53342 ], [ 9.053021, 36.524021 ], [ 9.052577, 36.513309 ], [ 9.050658, 36.502059000000145 ], [ 9.051683000000139, 36.492061000000149 ], [ 9.051669, 36.489231000000132 ], [ 9.051641, 36.483813 ], [ 9.051635, 36.482730000000117 ], [ 9.0360510000001, 36.47847 ], [ 9.030476000000135, 36.477415 ], [ 9.015807, 36.474639000000138 ], [ 9.001007, 36.47401 ], [ 8.978619, 36.471858000000111 ], [ 8.959619, 36.47010900000015 ], [ 8.95616, 36.46979 ], [ 8.953101000000117, 36.46951 ], [ 8.940754, 36.468371 ], [ 8.935953, 36.467929 ], [ 8.924223, 36.461830000000134 ], [ 8.923325, 36.460941000000105 ], [ 8.906790000000115, 36.44456 ], [ 8.903001000000131, 36.441439000000116 ], [ 8.899713, 36.438729 ], [ 8.886922, 36.433120000000145 ], [ 8.875766, 36.4304810000001 ], [ 8.875232, 36.430484 ], [ 8.862442000000158, 36.43056 ], [ 8.853001, 36.430639 ], [ 8.850386, 36.4306610000001 ], [ 8.833791, 36.425141 ], [ 8.820677, 36.425389 ], [ 8.794968, 36.421059 ], [ 8.776642, 36.417752000000121 ], [ 8.76059, 36.41689 ], [ 8.756615, 36.415932 ], [ 8.743341, 36.412731 ], [ 8.725819000000115, 36.411500000000103 ], [ 8.713947000000132, 36.412972 ], [ 8.698307, 36.419378 ], [ 8.69752, 36.4197 ], [ 8.685227, 36.42279 ], [ 8.678392000000144, 36.424508000000117 ], [ 8.676041000000112, 36.4251 ], [ 8.659779, 36.427669000000151 ], [ 8.659697, 36.427682 ], [ 8.64593, 36.422355 ], [ 8.62156, 36.412924000000146 ], [ 8.617570000000114, 36.411381 ], [ 8.61493, 36.4106 ], [ 8.603712000000144, 36.407279 ], [ 8.596174000000133, 36.407107 ], [ 8.590188, 36.406971 ], [ 8.589647, 36.407075 ], [ 8.577233, 36.409451 ], [ 8.566009, 36.410228 ], [ 8.558123, 36.409943 ], [ 8.556655, 36.409890000000132 ], [ 8.553334, 36.409770000000151 ], [ 8.543514, 36.404881000000103 ], [ 8.541066, 36.402785 ], [ 8.536681000000101, 36.39903 ], [ 8.529207, 36.393331000000103 ], [ 8.528801, 36.393036 ], [ 8.522419, 36.388401 ], [ 8.521110000000135, 36.387451 ], [ 8.502475, 36.385446 ], [ 8.50066, 36.385251 ], [ 8.496887, 36.384418 ], [ 8.484894, 36.381771 ], [ 8.471778, 36.373871 ], [ 8.465563000000145, 36.36889 ], [ 8.461157, 36.366352 ], [ 8.45119, 36.360611 ], [ 8.431706000000133, 36.362389 ], [ 8.420807, 36.36334 ], [ 8.41307, 36.364021 ], [ 8.392758, 36.366106000000116 ], [ 8.39344, 36.366557000000114 ], [ 8.39402, 36.369281000000115 ], [ 8.396842, 36.371528 ], [ 8.399187, 36.374293 ], [ 8.39916600000015, 36.376983 ], [ 8.397526, 36.380691 ], [ 8.396755000000155, 36.38248300000015 ], [ 8.397395, 36.384822 ], [ 8.398968000000139, 36.387092000000109 ], [ 8.400333000000103, 36.39067 ], [ 8.400833, 36.394065000000126 ], [ 8.399076, 36.39555300000012 ], [ 8.39675300000016, 36.396560000000136 ], [ 8.397312, 36.39917 ], [ 8.398886, 36.40132 ], [ 8.40174, 36.402965 ], [ 8.40437, 36.405578 ], [ 8.406344, 36.407725 ], [ 8.408125000000155, 36.408858 ], [ 8.410155, 36.410468000000151 ], [ 8.409249000000102, 36.41258 ], [ 8.408973, 36.415946 ], [ 8.408925, 36.418250000000114 ], [ 8.40853, 36.419749000000138 ], [ 8.408088000000134, 36.421428 ], [ 8.405796, 36.422423 ], [ 8.405252000000132, 36.422446 ], [ 8.402253000000144, 36.42257 ], [ 8.40009300000014, 36.422870000000103 ], [ 8.397684, 36.423037 ], [ 8.39474, 36.423175000000128 ], [ 8.392333, 36.423503 ], [ 8.390077, 36.424064 ], [ 8.386363, 36.424197000000106 ], [ 8.384169, 36.424716 ], [ 8.381518000000142, 36.425384000000122 ], [ 8.375307000000134, 36.427279 ], [ 8.372994, 36.428374 ], [ 8.370803000000137, 36.42982400000011 ], [ 8.369102000000112, 36.431395 ], [ 8.366798, 36.435429 ], [ 8.366435, 36.436065 ], [ 8.363801, 36.438617 ], [ 8.361654, 36.440211000000147 ], [ 8.35692, 36.44469 ], [ 8.354304000000127, 36.445357000000115 ], [ 8.35213, 36.443595 ], [ 8.350618, 36.441780000000108 ], [ 8.34952, 36.440459 ], [ 8.34813800000012, 36.438537 ], [ 8.345749, 36.436168000000123 ], [ 8.343541, 36.434401 ], [ 8.339808000000119, 36.433593 ], [ 8.337683, 36.43325700000014 ], [ 8.333628, 36.432193 ], [ 8.331063, 36.431254000000138 ], [ 8.328215, 36.431342000000143 ], [ 8.326268, 36.432033000000104 ], [ 8.32685, 36.433694 ], [ 8.326961000000153, 36.43401 ], [ 8.327082, 36.434356 ], [ 8.323971, 36.435931 ], [ 8.322243, 36.433371000000136 ], [ 8.32223, 36.433351 ], [ 8.321863, 36.432807 ], [ 8.319858, 36.429530000000113 ], [ 8.317251, 36.426433 ], [ 8.316660000000127, 36.432662000000107 ], [ 8.314462, 36.433188 ], [ 8.314427, 36.433196 ], [ 8.31181, 36.433383 ], [ 8.310419000000138, 36.433375000000126 ], [ 8.309212000000116, 36.433368 ], [ 8.30932, 36.433656 ], [ 8.310168000000147, 36.436019 ], [ 8.311114, 36.436727 ], [ 8.312207000000114, 36.437545 ], [ 8.308790000000158, 36.441745 ], [ 8.305871, 36.441516 ], [ 8.304222, 36.441386 ], [ 8.30224, 36.442756 ], [ 8.297972, 36.443374 ], [ 8.297594, 36.443301 ], [ 8.293162000000109, 36.442435000000103 ], [ 8.290802, 36.442779000000144 ], [ 8.288183, 36.443725 ], [ 8.28702200000015, 36.44465 ], [ 8.28657, 36.44501 ], [ 8.284594000000141, 36.44588 ], [ 8.281097000000159, 36.444659000000115 ], [ 8.280138, 36.444429 ], [ 8.278481, 36.444030000000112 ], [ 8.275392000000124, 36.443171 ], [ 8.272461, 36.4416 ], [ 8.268987, 36.440837 ], [ 8.26679, 36.440429 ], [ 8.264100000000155, 36.439097 ], [ 8.26202, 36.438540000000103 ], [ 8.259677000000124, 36.44088 ], [ 8.258065000000158, 36.442214000000149 ], [ 8.25522, 36.443627 ], [ 8.254641, 36.443912000000125 ], [ 8.252892, 36.444903 ], [ 8.252034000000151, 36.445388 ], [ 8.249614000000122, 36.446189 ], [ 8.245532, 36.446692 ], [ 8.244319, 36.446493000000146 ], [ 8.240908, 36.445933 ], [ 8.238179, 36.445517 ], [ 8.235629, 36.44564 ], [ 8.227342, 36.447097 ], [ 8.22493, 36.447486 ], [ 8.221072, 36.447631 ], [ 8.21751, 36.447204 ], [ 8.21532, 36.447016 ], [ 8.213220000000149, 36.446834000000138 ], [ 8.210838, 36.447112 ], [ 8.208119000000124, 36.44802 ], [ 8.207494000000111, 36.448297 ], [ 8.205551000000128, 36.449157000000127 ], [ 8.203340000000139, 36.450568000000146 ], [ 8.199827, 36.454287 ], [ 8.19795, 36.457126 ], [ 8.196959000000106, 36.459018000000128 ], [ 8.196723000000134, 36.459468 ], [ 8.195989, 36.459831 ], [ 8.193602, 36.461009 ], [ 8.18973, 36.46081 ], [ 8.185459, 36.460265000000106 ], [ 8.180586, 36.460026 ], [ 8.177576, 36.46001 ], [ 8.175118, 36.4601 ], [ 8.171526, 36.461491000000137 ], [ 8.169378000000108, 36.462822000000131 ], [ 8.166587000000106, 36.46581 ], [ 8.1667, 36.466068000000121 ], [ 8.166917, 36.467445 ], [ 8.16696, 36.468189000000109 ], [ 8.1669, 36.468418 ], [ 8.167065, 36.468647000000146 ], [ 8.166344, 36.468937000000153 ], [ 8.166, 36.469337 ], [ 8.165731, 36.469795 ], [ 8.165199, 36.470596000000114 ], [ 8.164825, 36.47105 ], [ 8.164603000000113, 36.471401000000128 ], [ 8.164477000000147, 36.471916 ], [ 8.164425000000108, 36.472374 ], [ 8.164425000000108, 36.472832 ], [ 8.164401, 36.47323200000011 ], [ 8.164315, 36.473576000000151 ], [ 8.16415000000012, 36.473862 ], [ 8.163858000000118, 36.474209 ], [ 8.163422, 36.474548 ], [ 8.163060000000144, 36.474895 ], [ 8.162769, 36.475239 ], [ 8.161829, 36.476212 ], [ 8.161566, 36.476559 ], [ 8.161318, 36.476845 ], [ 8.161142, 36.477184 ], [ 8.160873, 36.477531 ], [ 8.160678, 36.477928000000134 ], [ 8.160581, 36.478218 ], [ 8.160484, 36.478733000000148 ], [ 8.160443000000157, 36.479134000000101 ], [ 8.16038, 36.48017 ], [ 8.16038, 36.480682000000115 ], [ 8.160431, 36.481083 ], [ 8.161026, 36.482628 ], [ 8.161211, 36.483047 ], [ 8.161354, 36.483372 ], [ 8.161468, 36.483948 ], [ 8.161519, 36.484406 ], [ 8.161456000000101, 36.484921 ], [ 8.161245, 36.485493 ], [ 8.161056, 36.485893000000146 ], [ 8.161176, 36.486355 ], [ 8.16142, 36.48687 ], [ 8.16156500000011, 36.487385000000131 ], [ 8.161721, 36.487728000000118 ], [ 8.161794, 36.48819 ], [ 8.161566, 36.489044 ], [ 8.161342000000104, 36.490017000000137 ], [ 8.16117, 36.490593 ], [ 8.16098600000015, 36.490993 ], [ 8.16046, 36.491398 ], [ 8.160008, 36.49168 ], [ 8.158947, 36.492138000000125 ], [ 8.158408, 36.492428000000132 ], [ 8.157704, 36.49271 ], [ 8.157119, 36.492886 ], [ 8.157005, 36.492873 ], [ 8.156558, 36.492825 ], [ 8.155735, 36.492908 ], [ 8.155395000000112, 36.492943000000139 ], [ 8.154386000000102, 36.493172 ], [ 8.153980000000104, 36.493343000000152 ], [ 8.153710000000103, 36.49392 ], [ 8.153515, 36.49437300000011 ], [ 8.153012000000103, 36.495178000000124 ], [ 8.152891, 36.495579 ], [ 8.153218, 36.49604 ], [ 8.153612, 36.496323 ], [ 8.154014, 36.496552000000122 ], [ 8.15437, 36.49678 ], [ 8.154896, 36.497066 ], [ 8.155320000000131, 36.497467000000142 ], [ 8.155349, 36.49775 ], [ 8.155229, 36.49816 ], [ 8.155132, 36.498558 ], [ 8.155096, 36.498787000000107 ], [ 8.155135, 36.498823 ], [ 8.155333, 36.499012000000107 ], [ 8.155618, 36.499187 ], [ 8.155991, 36.499302000000114 ], [ 8.156443000000138, 36.49941600000011 ], [ 8.15689, 36.499531 ], [ 8.15767, 36.49941600000011 ], [ 8.15831, 36.499187 ], [ 8.15938, 36.498959000000127 ], [ 8.159915, 36.498726 ], [ 8.160403, 36.498558 ], [ 8.160981000000106, 36.4984970000001 ], [ 8.161428000000114, 36.498501 ], [ 8.16205, 36.498615 ], [ 8.162608, 36.4989 ], [ 8.162986, 36.49913 ], [ 8.163445, 36.499359 ], [ 8.163949, 36.499760000000151 ], [ 8.164671, 36.50027 ], [ 8.164900000000159, 36.50039 ], [ 8.165427, 36.500332 ], [ 8.166763000000117, 36.50045 ], [ 8.16737, 36.500618 ], [ 8.167632, 36.500718 ], [ 8.167816, 36.500790000000109 ], [ 8.168354000000136, 36.501194 ], [ 8.169164, 36.501938 ], [ 8.17039, 36.5028 ], [ 8.170883000000117, 36.503086 ], [ 8.172057000000109, 36.50394 ], [ 8.172544, 36.504059 ], [ 8.172933000000114, 36.504574 ], [ 8.173307000000136, 36.505032 ], [ 8.173787, 36.505893000000128 ], [ 8.173817, 36.50658 ], [ 8.173853, 36.506737 ], [ 8.17393600000014, 36.507095000000106 ], [ 8.17392, 36.507496 ], [ 8.174183000000141, 36.50927 ], [ 8.174418, 36.50961 ], [ 8.17477300000013, 36.509903 ], [ 8.175529000000154, 36.510188 ], [ 8.175724000000116, 36.510474 ], [ 8.175867, 36.510932000000139 ], [ 8.175867, 36.51133 ], [ 8.175896000000137, 36.51179500000012 ], [ 8.175793000000112, 36.51208 ], [ 8.175885000000108, 36.512423 ], [ 8.176113000000157, 36.512768 ], [ 8.17656600000015, 36.513164 ], [ 8.177311000000145, 36.51334 ], [ 8.178479000000152, 36.513511 ], [ 8.179094, 36.513682000000131 ], [ 8.180353000000139, 36.513911 ], [ 8.181568, 36.514197 ], [ 8.182112, 36.513968000000148 ], [ 8.183, 36.513629000000151 ], [ 8.183648, 36.513282 ], [ 8.1848, 36.512767 ], [ 8.185557000000131, 36.51236 ], [ 8.186209, 36.512134000000117 ], [ 8.18758, 36.511966 ], [ 8.188089, 36.511794 ], [ 8.188673, 36.511565 ], [ 8.189092, 36.5111 ], [ 8.189223, 36.510646 ], [ 8.189338000000134, 36.51036 ], [ 8.189544000000126, 36.510131000000115 ], [ 8.1901170000001, 36.51007 ], [ 8.190725000000157, 36.509902 ], [ 8.191131000000155, 36.50973 ], [ 8.191836, 36.509387 ], [ 8.192386000000113, 36.509158 ], [ 8.192953000000102, 36.508986 ], [ 8.193492000000106, 36.508872 ], [ 8.19416, 36.508986 ], [ 8.194529000000102, 36.508868 ], [ 8.194844, 36.508468 ], [ 8.19513000000012, 36.508067 ], [ 8.195571, 36.507838000000106 ], [ 8.196133000000145, 36.507838000000106 ], [ 8.196356, 36.507956 ], [ 8.197135000000117, 36.508811000000151 ], [ 8.197508, 36.509097 ], [ 8.198579, 36.509501 ], [ 8.199926000000119, 36.509959 ], [ 8.200493000000108, 36.510188 ], [ 8.201072, 36.51036 ], [ 8.201697, 36.510589000000152 ], [ 8.203913000000114, 36.511161 ], [ 8.20447, 36.511222000000146 ], [ 8.205117, 36.51133 ], [ 8.205551000000128, 36.511504 ], [ 8.206057, 36.51185 ], [ 8.206922, 36.512595 ], [ 8.207873, 36.513282 ], [ 8.209644, 36.513968000000148 ], [ 8.210366, 36.51414 ], [ 8.211006, 36.514255000000105 ], [ 8.212297000000149, 36.514541000000122 ], [ 8.213064, 36.514659000000108 ], [ 8.214422000000127, 36.514831000000129 ], [ 8.215293, 36.515002 ], [ 8.216559, 36.51512 ], [ 8.218037, 36.515403 ], [ 8.218896, 36.515456000000142 ], [ 8.220163000000127, 36.515632000000153 ], [ 8.22123, 36.515513 ], [ 8.221492000000126, 36.515513 ], [ 8.221836, 36.515689 ], [ 8.222311, 36.51615 ], [ 8.222862000000134, 36.51649 ], [ 8.223153, 36.516719 ], [ 8.223395, 36.517005 ], [ 8.223531, 36.517291000000114 ], [ 8.223503, 36.517863 ], [ 8.22339, 36.51884 ], [ 8.223458, 36.519355 ], [ 8.223715, 36.519698000000119 ], [ 8.22414, 36.520099 ], [ 8.224707, 36.520442 ], [ 8.225303, 36.520503000000133 ], [ 8.225876000000142, 36.520503000000133 ], [ 8.226466, 36.52056 ], [ 8.227073, 36.52078900000015 ], [ 8.227721, 36.521129 ], [ 8.228218, 36.5213 ], [ 8.228986, 36.521357 ], [ 8.229698000000155, 36.521247 ], [ 8.231003000000157, 36.52078900000015 ], [ 8.231273000000101, 36.5209 ], [ 8.231943000000115, 36.521533 ], [ 8.2323, 36.521991000000128 ], [ 8.23264, 36.522338000000104 ], [ 8.23322, 36.522567 ], [ 8.233879, 36.52291 ], [ 8.23443, 36.523139 ], [ 8.234922, 36.523478 ], [ 8.235702000000117, 36.523883 ], [ 8.236354, 36.524169 ], [ 8.236997000000144, 36.524341 ], [ 8.23735, 36.524627000000123 ], [ 8.237718, 36.525084000000106 ], [ 8.238182000000108, 36.525432 ], [ 8.238733, 36.525599 ], [ 8.239202000000148, 36.525599 ], [ 8.2402790000001, 36.525313 ], [ 8.240773000000104, 36.525256000000127 ], [ 8.24134, 36.525428000000147 ], [ 8.241660000000138, 36.525599 ], [ 8.242021000000136, 36.526057000000151 ], [ 8.242492, 36.526515 ], [ 8.24294, 36.52686 ], [ 8.243367000000148, 36.527263 ], [ 8.24376, 36.527545000000146 ], [ 8.244038, 36.527835000000152 ], [ 8.24455, 36.52795 ], [ 8.244978, 36.527778 ], [ 8.245669, 36.527725 ], [ 8.24573, 36.52772 ], [ 8.246308000000113, 36.52772 ], [ 8.246731000000125, 36.527835000000152 ], [ 8.24738, 36.52846 ], [ 8.247711, 36.528983 ], [ 8.248078, 36.529437 ], [ 8.248357, 36.530299000000127 ], [ 8.248461, 36.530418 ], [ 8.248708, 36.5307 ], [ 8.24883, 36.530986 ], [ 8.248788, 36.531901000000119 ], [ 8.248925, 36.532134 ], [ 8.249062, 36.532307 ], [ 8.249653000000137, 36.53305 ], [ 8.250289, 36.53356 ], [ 8.250754, 36.533965 ], [ 8.25168200000013, 36.534537000000114 ], [ 8.25209, 36.534823000000131 ], [ 8.252489000000139, 36.534995000000151 ], [ 8.253411, 36.535457 ], [ 8.253762000000108, 36.53551 ], [ 8.254368, 36.535685 ], [ 8.254775000000109, 36.535743 ], [ 8.255796, 36.535743 ], [ 8.255899, 36.535743 ], [ 8.256368, 36.535972 ], [ 8.256387, 36.536045 ], [ 8.256505, 36.536487000000136 ], [ 8.256689, 36.536715 ], [ 8.257044, 36.536944000000119 ], [ 8.257371, 36.537059 ], [ 8.258029, 36.537059 ], [ 8.258071000000143, 36.536904 ], [ 8.258076, 36.536887 ], [ 8.2583, 36.536776 ], [ 8.258631, 36.536773 ], [ 8.259113, 36.536601 ], [ 8.259342000000117, 36.536544 ], [ 8.259651000000133, 36.536372 ], [ 8.259938, 36.536258 ], [ 8.260219, 36.536086 ], [ 8.26034, 36.536029 ],
```

In order for me to manipulate it with Python and display it, I need to convert it into a GeoJSON file. Any suggestions on how to do that? I have already tried [geojson.io](https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) but the website crashes each time I copy-paste the data (probably due to its length).

Edit: I have also tried converting the text file into a Json file :

```
# Python program to convert text 
# file to JSON 


import json 


# the file to be converted to 
# json format 
filename = 'Jendouba.txt'

# dictionary where the lines from 
# text will be stored 
dict1 = {} 

# creating dictionary 
with open(filename) as fh: 

    for line in fh: 

        # reads each line and trims of extra the spaces 
        # and gives only the valid words 
        command, description = line.strip().split(None, 1) 

        dict1[command] = description.strip() 

# creating json file 
# the JSON file is named as test1 
out_file = open("Jendouba.json", "w") 
json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent = 4, sort_keys = False) 
out_file.close()
```

Therefore, is it possible to go :

1. from Text file to GeoJson file directly
2. from text file-->Json-->GeoJson 
   Using Pyhton in both cases?

Comment: 1) Does your file actually end with `[ 8.26034, 36.536029 ],` or has it been truncated here? 2) If it is valid JSON (i.e. ends without being truncated) it looks as though it *already is* a GeoJSON file.

Comment: First off, you should read the file and convert it to JSON in Python (which is already answered in [so]), then you'll be ready to start evaluating GeoJSON conformance.

Comment: @alphabetasoup no it's pretty lengthy so I just put a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Using python the following worked for me:

```
# Convert text file to JSON 
import json 
with open('Jendouba.txt') as json_file:     # name of the text file
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Convert JSON to GeoJson 
from geojson import dump
with open('Jendouba.geojson', 'w') as f:   # name of the output geojson file
   dump(data, f)
```

Comment: If that worked, then simply renaming the file to `Jendouba.geojson` is all you need to do.

Comment: Yeah basically just load and dump in the new format.

Comment: @RimSleimi No, you don't even need to load it and dump it; if this code works then `Jendouba.txt` is *already a file containing GeoJSON data*, it just has a misleading file extension (`.txt` instead of `.json` or `.geojson`).

Comment: This is actually true the text file has GeoJSON data